# Conflicting types for (pointer) in C

Tags: c

I need to print random numbers between 0 and 100 with pointers to the screen but i got an error. The error is;

```
conflicting types for 'sayilar'
```

And here is my code ;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int sayilar[100];
    int i;
    int *sayilar=(int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        sayilar[i]=rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\t",*(sayilar+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declared `sayilar` twice (once as an array, once as a pointer) - why are you doing that?

Comment: You're declaring `sayilar` twice with different types. Delete either of them, preferably the second one. Also `*(sayilar+i)` is more elegantly written as `sayilar[i]`. Also, since you're only printing the numbers without using them afterwards, you don't need that array at all.

Comment: The compiler message is pretty self-explanatory. You can't have two variables of different types with the same name. Neither C nor common sense allows that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to allocate memory for sayilar. The compiler will do it for you automatically since you declared the `sayilar` as an array of integers. Just get rid of the second declaration of sayilar and it will be ok.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int sayilar[100];
    int i;
    // get rid of second declaration of sayilar.
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        sayilar[i]=rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\t",*(sayilar+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd be happier if you had said "the compiler will do it for you automatically" ;-) (because it is a local variable it has, in C/C++ terms, "automatic storage duration", as opposed to the "static storage duration" of e.g. global variables).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I actually didn't mean statically but automatically so I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: `i<=100` should also be `i<100` otherwise the array will be accessed out of bounds

Comment: Since I focused on the main problem didn't concentrate on the rest. Thanks for letting me  know.